# iMessage falsely reports "could not send"

Tags: messages

For some reason, since Monday iMessage on the iPhone 4S always tells me it couldn't deliver my message but the messages go through. Anybody have the same problem? Any idea how to fix it? I'm not the only one, a couple friends have it too, but Google didn't help.

Comment: I've noticed this *occasionally* myself. Does it happen on every text? Have you rebooted the phone(s)?

Comment: Yes it does and yes I did, didn't fix it :-(

Comment: Does it happen on every kind of network? (3G, WiFi, ...) What are the similarities and the differences between your and your friends' phones? (same iPhone, same network, ...)

Comment: 3G and Wifi, 2x 4S, 2x 3GS, three of which are on T-Mobile (Germany), the other one is on E-Plus (also Germany)

Comment: That's not fixable unless you have a very stable connection with Apple's server with little ping.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a status page to show availability of all the different services: [Apple System Status](http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/). Worth checking in these moments, it doesn't always look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it's official, it's not a bug, it's a temporary problem with iCloud service.

http://www.heise.de/mac-and-i/meldung/iCloud-Dienste-und-iMessage-zeitweise-gestoert-1622986.html (in german, [english as translated by Google](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heise.de%2Fmac-and-i%2Fmeldung%2FiCloud-Dienste-und-iMessage-zeitweise-gestoert-1622986.html&act=url))